# Writing Tags with NfcV tag.transceive

Tags: java, android, nfc, rfid, iso-15693

I'm working on an application about NFC writing.
Lets call it Writer... I am writing data to a NfcV tag.

The string I am trying to write is `String test = "this is\ta real\ttestcase\tyou tag";`

To write data I'm using NfcV's `transceive` method.
So this is my writer-method:

```
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb);
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        formatter.format("%02X", b);
    }
    formatter.close();
    return sb.toString();
}

public void write(View v) {
    try {
        String[] tagInfoArray = new String[tagData.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < tagData.size(); i++)
            tagInfoArray[i] = tagData.get(i).getText().toString();

        String tagInfo = join(tagInfoArray, "\t");
        //String test = "this is\ta real\ttestcase\tyou tag";
        writeTag(tag, tagInfo);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "How about providing a tag!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } finally {
        write.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.bluebutton);
    }
}

public String join(String[] input, String delim) {
    String output = "";
    if (input.length > 0)
        output += input[0];
    if (input.length > 1)
        for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++)
            output += delim + input[i];
    return output;
}

public void exitButton(View v) {
    this.foreground.disableForeground();
    System.exit(0);
}

public void writeTag(Tag tag, String data) {
    NfcV myTag = NfcV.get(tag);
    try {
        myTag.connect();
        if (myTag.isConnected()) {
            byte[] info = data.getBytes();
            int dataLength = info.length;
            if (data.length()/4 <= 64){ 
                byte[] args = new byte[15];
                args[0] = 0x20;
                args[1] = 0x21;
                byte[] id = tag.getId();
                for (int o=0; o<8; o++)
                    args[o+2] = id[o];
                for (int i = 0; i<64; i++) {
                    args[10] = (byte) i;
                    args[11] = 0x00;
                    args[12] = 0x00;
                    args[13] = 0x00;
                    args[14] = 0x00;
                    byte[] out = myTag.transceive(args);
                    String out2 = bytesToHex(out);
                    System.out.println("1:.. " + printHex(out2));
                }
                for (int i = 0; i<=dataLength/4; i++) {
                    args[10] = (byte) i;
                    args[11] = getByte(info, (i*4)+0);
                    args[12] = getByte(info, (i*4)+1);
                    args[13] = getByte(info, (i*4)+2);
                    args[14] = getByte(info, (i*4)+3);
                    byte[] out = myTag.transceive(args);
                    String out2 = bytesToHex(out);
                    System.out.println("2:.. " + printHex(out2));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (myTag != null) {
            try {
                myTag.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

public static byte getByte(byte[] input, int key){
    try {
        return input[key];
    } catch (Exception e){
        return (byte)0x00;
    }
}

public String printByte(byte[] input){
    try {
        return new String(input, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}

public String printHex(String input){
    return input;
}
```

So when im writing stuff the outcome is not what I am expecting it to be. It's either not writing at all, or just writing parts, while not overwriting, what has been on the tag before.

This is the output:

```
11-05 15:32:33.139: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:33.249: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:33.349: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:33.449: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:33.549: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:33.649: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00 
11-05 15:32:33.759: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:33.859: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:33.959: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:34.059: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:34.159: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:34.259: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:34.359: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:34.469: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:34.569: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:34.669: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:34.769: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:34.869: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:34.979: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:35.079: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:35.179: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:35.289: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:35.389: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:35.489: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:35.589: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:35.689: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:35.789: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:35.889: I/System.out(1390): 1:.. 00
11-05 15:32:35.989: I/System.out(1390): Transceive failed
```

Comment: What results do you receive for the `transceive()`-method? What tag (manufacturer, type) do you use? Does it support the write single block command with option_flag = 0? Is the memory programmable multiple times?

Comment: Result: "Transceive failed", tag:(Infineon Technologies Ag, Type V)

Comment: "Type V" is not really helpful. A product name would help...

Comment: Regarding the transceive failed error: does this happen while sending the first command or only after addressing a specific block?

Comment: Btw. `myTag.getMaxTransceiveLength()` does not provide the memory size of the tag but the transceive buffer size, so you definitely do not want to use it as the upper bound of that for-loop.

Comment: On i=24 .. for the second loop, not the first... Error ist "Transceive failed"... or before with "Tag lost"

Comment: Remember that args[2] is the block number and not a byte address so you are currently using only every 4th block. Still that does not really explain why it would fail at i=24 (i.e. block 24). There does not seem to be a vicinity tag with 24 * 4 = 96 bytes of user memory in [Infineon's my-d product range](http://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/channel.html?channel=db3a3043294a355801296437a1d15143).

Comment: You might want to try the addressed version of the write command to get error information from the tag: `0x20 0x21 UID0 UID1 UID2 UID3 UID4 UID5 UID6 UID7(=0xE0) i B0 B1 B2 B3`. Where `UID[0..7]` is the tag's ID.

Comment: so, how do i have to set the byte[] ?... args[0] is the Flag, args[1] is the command, args[2] targetblock... how do i address that? and args[3..6] the 4 information parts with 2 bytes each...

Comment: see the command structure in my last comment: `byte args[] = { 0x20 0x21 UID0 UID1 UID2 UID3 UID4 UID5 UID6 UID7(=0xE0) i B0 B1 B2 B3 };`

Comment: How do i get the ID... is it the dsfID ?... btw i'm really glad you are helping me.. i just realized who you are ;)

Comment: No it's the `tag.getID()`. I'm not sure about the byte order you get from `getID()`, just fill it into UID0..7 so that UID7 gets set to `0xE0` (so in case the ID you get from `getID()` has its first byte set to `0xE0`, you need to reverse the byte order).

Comment: By the way.. is my thought-process right, when im first overwriting all the Block with 0x00, before writing new data? Also i have edited the Code in the Question to what i have atm.

Comment: You definitely want to replace `id[i]` with `id[o]`. Also remember that with `args[10] = (byte) i;` within your for-loops you will effectively only write every 4th block (leaving 3 blocks untouched in between) so you might want to replace that with `args[10] = (byte) (i/4);`. (Note that you won't reach the 24th block with your erase-loop then as 64/4 = 16 blocks.)

Comment: ok.. fxixed the code... id[i] ofc was not intended :D....if `myTag.getMaxTransceiveLength()` does not tell me, how many blocks there are... how can i find that out ?

Comment: there is no real standard approach for that, either the tag tells you through some custom command or you can determine the tag type based on its UID and other parameters and then determine the size based on that tag type information (typically manufacturers provide identification procedures in their product manuals).

Comment: So what result (error code) do you receive in `out` now? And at what `i`?

Comment: I updated the question with all you need to know... well thats weird output...

Comment: ok.. i just successfully wrote to a tag.. it seems im getting problems, with tags, that are to small

Comment: It would help if you converted the output to hexadecimal values instead. This way it would be easier to decode the value into status flags.

Comment: Im now at a Point , where i can read and write tags... my only problem left is, that i dont know how often to loop, as i have different sized tags.

Comment: if all of them are Infineon my-d tags, then you can use the identification procedure described in the handbook for my-d vicinity (should be available on their website). similar procedures exist for TI's tags and I believe also for NXP's ICODE.

Comment: btw. another (but less reliable) approach would be to write (or better read) blocks on the tag until you encounter the `IOException`. then take this block index as upper bound for the tag's memory. then disconnect and reconnect the tag and you can continue to write, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the various issues in the initial post:

- Reading or writing from/to blocks bejond the tag size will result in IOExceptions caused by the tag stopping to respond.
- `NfcV.getMaxTransceiveLength()` returns information about the maximum number of bytes that can be exchanged in one command/one response. It does **not** provide information about the tag size!.
- Unfortunately there is no one-for-all approach to detect the actual size of a tag. A possible approach would be to try to detect the type of tag (many NfcV tags encode the exact tag type into their ID, so you could use `Tag.getId()` to get the ID and parse it according to the tag manufacturers' data sheets). Another approach is to read until the first IOException and infer the tag size from that information. You can later reconnect the tag to continue reading/writing. However, keep in mind that any other interruptions in communication (e.g. the user not properly scanning the tag) may also lead to IOExceptions and may consequently falsify your estimated tag size.
- The block index parameter of the ISO/IEC 15693 read/write single block commands is in blocks and not in bytes.

Comment: and 1 block = 4 Bytes

Answer (score 2):

Don't know for the Infineon Technologies, but for NXP ICODE and TI tags (ISO15693) exists the `Get System Information` command. I'll attach an image with the response bytes. In this example the number of blocks is 0x3F + 1. The 0x03 + 1 is the number of bytes per block. So 3f=63 and 03=3, total memory = (63+1)*(3+1) = 256bytes

[image: Response to Get system information command]

I use it like this (I'm sending an addressed command, with the tag id included in the command, but it's not necessary):

```
        nfcV = NfcV.get(tag);
        byte[] id = tag.getId();

        if (nfcV != null) {

            byte[] infoCmd = new byte[2 + id.length];
            // set "addressed" flag
            infoCmd[0] = 0x20; 
            // ISO 15693 Get System Information command byte
            infoCmd[1] = 0x2B;
            //adding the tag id
            System.arraycopy(id, 0, infoCmd, 2, id.length); 

            int memoryBlocks = null; 
            try {
                nfcV.connect();
                byte[] data = nfcV.transceive(infoCmd);

                memoryBlocks = Integer.parseInt(String.format("%02X", data[data.length-3]), 16);

            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            finally {
                try {
                    nfcV.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```